# DirectX Anisotropic Filtering Option Levels and Future Proofing It

Tags: directx

Ok so i have a configuration program for a 3d directx application. When querying the AF level i get a 16. If 16 is available will 8, 4 and 2 always be available? and when / if in the future levels go up to 32 / 64, will these lower values be available too?

will this always be the case? can i always divide the max af level by two until i arrive at 2 to obtain all the possible af levels? Lastly if that is not the case is there a way to query directx much in the same way you can check if the hardware supports a multi-sample level to see if it supports the select anisotropic filtering level?

Comment: For Clarification the question can be read as: If an anisotropic filtering level of 16 is returned as the max. will a level of 8 always be supported?

Comment: Values range from 1 to the value that is specified in the MaxAnisotropy member of the D3DCAPS9 structure. The default value is 1. If i read this right it always will support anything below MAX.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the query is for the *maximum* anisotropy, not the one value you can set it to. Also, there's nothing I can find in the docs that says that the anisotropy you set must be a power of two (though admittedly, I only did a quick search).

Comment: i am aware. just wanted to make sure that if 16 is available 8,4,2 will always be available so i can add them as options.